# OpenShift WordPress - How to define WP_CONTENT_DIR and WP_CONTENT_URL correctly to fix broken theme options in some themes?

Tags: php, wordpress, openshift

The theme options panel does not load correctly with certain themes on OpenShift.

According to the [theme developer](https://wordpress.org/support/topic/does-not-work-on-openshift-platform#post-5506426) this is because the theme

> is built using the redux options framework. The developers of redux
>   use WP_CONTENT_DIR and WP_CONTENT_URL two core constants defined by
>   WordPress. If they are not correctly defined then the theme options
>   don't load correctly.

I have tried to define them correctly in wp-config.php without success. My changes have resulted in the website returning a blank page or without CSS. I understand it is important where I place them in wp-config, perhaps this is part of the problem.
For example, adding the first two lines:

```
define( 'WP_CONTENT_DIR', dirname( __FILE__ ) . 'OPENSHIFT_DATA_DIR/current/wp-content' );
define( 'WP_CONTENT_URL', 'http://' . $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] . '/OPENSHIFT_DATA_DIR/current/wp-content' );

// absolute path to the WordPress directory
if ( !defined('ABSPATH') )
  define('ABSPATH', dirname(__FILE__) . '/');

// tell WordPress where the plugins directory really is
if ( !defined('WP_PLUGIN_DIR') && is_link(ABSPATH . '/wp-content/plugins') )
  define('WP_PLUGIN_DIR', realpath(ABSPATH . '/wp-content/plugins'));

// sets up WordPress vars and included files
require_once(ABSPATH . 'wp-settings.php');
```

And variations of the following:

```
define ('WP_CONTENT_DIR','/full/path/to/your/content/dir');
define ('WP_CONTENT_URL','http://example.com/full/path/to/your/content/dirs/url');

define( 'WP_CONTENT_DIR', dirname(__FILE__) . '/wp-content' );
define( 'WP_CONTENT_URL', 'http://example.com/wp-content' );

define(‘WP_CONTENT_DIR’, $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . ‘/wp-content’);
define(‘WP_CONTENT_URL’, ‘http://example.com/wp-content’);

define( 'WP_CONTENT_DIR', dirname( __FILE__ ) . 'path/to/wp-content' );
define( 'WP_CONTENT_URL', 'http://' . $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] . '/path/to/wp-content' );
```

I have also tried defining the path simmilar to these examples:

```
/var/lib/openshift/12345678901234567890123456/app-root/data
OPENSHIFT_DATA_DIR/current/wp-content
```

If anyone could point me in the right direction I will be most grateful.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: @nenonem I have the same problem. Have you found out the solution?

Comment: Unfortunately not.  I found some, but not all functions that were controlled in Theme Options, could also be controlled in WordPress dashboard Appearance > Customize. The most efficient way for me to deal with the problem was to make changes in local development and then migrate the database using the WP Migrate DB plugin.